# How to throw exception from SQL server 2005 function?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

When I try to use RaiseError, I get the following compilation issue

> Msg 443, Level 16, State 14, Procedure ConvertSessionToCurr, Line 19
>   Invalid use of a side-effecting operator 'RAISERROR' within a
>   function.

So how do we handle exception in a function/ Change it to a out param stored proc? That really  sounds like a bummer!

Comment: You could have the function return NULL if an error occurs, depending upon what your application does with the function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Options:

- Return NULL or some sentinel value
- Use a stored procedure
- Make it inline code

My thought is that if you need RAISERROR in a UDF you're using it wrong...

Comment: My thought is that if you need RAISERROR in a UDF you're using it wrong...?  Serious!

Comment: If you return a null or specific sentinel value, how do you pass the error code back to the caller?