# Why can't I use procedures inside functions in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I know that functions always returns a value and I'll make a sp which return a value as the function returns and want to calling it inside the function. How might I do this?

Comment: You can't call sql stored procedures in a function, [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx).

Comment: Because, according to MSDN: *User-defined functions cannot be used to perform actions that modify the database state.* -- Calling a stored procedure most likely will modify the database state - therefore it's not allowed inside a function.

Comment: @Andomar: I know, but why we can't call any specific reason.

Comment: @marc_s: But inside function I'll just perform select command.
and it'll not modify the database state. Now in this select scenario
why not??

Comment: Yes, in your case, that might be so - but SQL Server cannot assume that all stored procedures will never ever change the database state. Since that cannot be assumed, you cannot use stored procedures inside a function. If it really is just a simple SELECT - just copy that SELECT into your function ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some thoughts after your comments above

- *Generally* stored procedures can do almost anything. So it is safer to disallow them
- The engine can't reliably work out what your stored procedure does
  What about nesting of stored procedures, or recursion, or linked server calls or OPENQUERY calls, and many many other things
- What if someone change it later to do some writes? 
  You can't schema-bind a UDF to a stored procedure
- [Error throwing/handling is a state change even if the stored procedure is read only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7789100/27535)

This is how SQL Server behaves for good reasons

Comment: Ok.. database hunks have not given functionality of calling stored proc inside function to just to avoid changes in Procedures..??
But, I didn't think so..
Their should must be some other reason!

Comment: @PrashantGupta: I gave more than that one reason: read my complete answer. Now, deal with it and stop ignoring everyone who took time to answer/comment please

Comment: Hey @gbn:
I'm agree with your ans as well as I'm not ignoring anyone
and also very much thankful to everyone who made comment/ans.
But if you don't want to clarify its OK for me..
I'll must find some better way to get my answer because till now I'm not satisfied with the ans.
And please tell me the points where I made wrong cross questions?